# How avoid duplication of rows when populating data from core data on a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I'm working on a project that is written in swift 3.0. My requirement is to retrieve and populate the data on a table view which is saved on CoreData that I enter on some text fields, thus once a row is selected I wants to update that record (re-assign values on my text fields and save).
Basically I have an entity named "UserIncome" and it got few attributes. Thus, when I wants to edit the data that I entered, I tap on a row and it'll direct me to the ViewController where I initially entered those data. However when I click the add button and save the data im getting duplicated data and they get populate in my table view. how can I stop this. The code of the class where i save data as follow.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddIncomeViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var toDateView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var setDateFromView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var datePickerTo: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var datePickerFrom: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var dropDowntableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var fromTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var toTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var incomeTypeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var incomeNameTextField: UITextField!

var myArray = ["Recurring Income", "Other Income"]

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var store : UserIncome?
var otherInc : UserIncome?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

 if let s = store {
    incomeNameTextField.text = s.incomeName
    amountTextField.text = s.amount
    fromTextField.text = s.fromDate
    toTextField.text = s.toDate
    incomeTypeLabel.text = s.incomeType

 }
 if let o = otherInc {
    incomeNameTextField.text = o.incomeName
    amountTextField.text = o.amount
    fromTextField.text = o.fromDate
    toTextField.text = o.toDate
    incomeTypeLabel.text = o.incomeType


  }


 }


 @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

 }


 @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

 if store == nil{

  let storeDesciption = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserIncome", in: context)

    store = UserIncome(entity:storeDesciption! , insertInto: context)
    //otherInc = UserIncome(entity:storeDesciption! , insertInto: context)

 }
 if otherInc == nil{
    let storeDesciption = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserIncome", in: context)

    otherInc = UserIncome(entity:storeDesciption! , insertInto: context)


 }


store?.incomeName = incomeNameTextField.text
store?.amount = amountTextField.text
store?.fromDate = fromTextField.text
store?.toDate = toTextField.text
store?.incomeType = incomeTypeLabel.text

otherInc?.incomeName = incomeNameTextField.text
otherInc?.amount = amountTextField.text
otherInc?.fromDate = fromTextField.text
otherInc?.toDate = toTextField.text
otherInc?.incomeType = incomeTypeLabel.text

var error : NSError?

(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
 if let err = error{

    let a = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: err.localizedFailureReason, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    a.show()
 }else {
    let a =  UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Successfully saved", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    a.show()
    //  navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you mean preventing duplicate user input or duplicate table cells of existing data?

Comment: No sir, basically when i click on the add button the data gets added two times to my tableView. I think the issue is with the addButtonPressed method.

Comment: You are creating a `UserIncome` object twice. Why?

Comment: Because I have two different tableViews in the viewController where i retrieve data. So if a particular row is selected in that VC, a segue will be fired and  data will be passed to the class above. The two table views have two distinct data sets

Comment: Core Data objects should be shared. That is your problem. How are you filling your table views? You should be using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: you are absolutely correct the object could be shared. Thats where the error was.. errr I feel so stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added two different `UserIncome` objects. You should add one, and share it for your table views.